# Returning value line by line

Tags: java, spring, java.util.scanner

I've got two classes:

```
public class SwimmingWorkout implements Workout {

    @Override
    public String getWorkout() {
        File fr = new File("swimmingWorkout_beginner.txt");

        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(fr);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String val = "";
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            val = val + sc.nextLine();
        }

        sc.close();
        return val;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        Workout workout = context.getBean("myWorkout", Workout.class);
        System.out.println(workout.getWorkout());
        context.close();
    }

}
```

After running I have got all lines from file printed in one line. What I want to do is to return `val` value with each line printed in new line, not in one. How can I do this?

Comment: Tip 1: look at your code and try to figure out which statement "removes" the linebreak. When you have found the statement, insert a linebreak. Tip 2: you only have to modify/insert a single line.

Comment: You could I suppose put each line you read into an ArrayList and have your method return that list instead of a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fetch a line from the Scanner the delimiter is stripped out.  In this case the delimiter is the newline.  So you have to add it back  One way to add it back is liek this:

```
val = val + sc.nextLine() + "\n";
```

There are other ways too.  For example you can use a StringBuilder or StringJoiner.  But the one I pasted here is quick to try.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the break line string at the end of each line you got

From

```
val = val + sc.nextLine();
```

To

```
val = val + sc.nextLine() + "\n";
```

"**\n**" mean **newline**

**OR**

You can print each time you got a new line (In case you just only want to show up all the data you got)

From

```
System.out.println(workout.getWorkout());
```

To

```
workout.getWorkout();
```

And in getWorkout() method :

From

```
val = val + sc.nextLine();
```

To

```
System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is probably storing all your values in an ArrayList (I'll name it values in this example) then in a for loop print it all out line by line:

```
// This line will go outside of your method in SwimmingWorkout near top
ArrayList<Integer> values=new ArrayList<Integer>();

// this will go at the bottom of your SwimmingWorkout method just before you return the value
values.add(val);
```

When the app first loads in your separate class, write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
System.out.println(values.get(i));
}
```

These lines will print each value line by line in an efficient manner.